# Translating Jefferson's quote on priests and science

Tags: sentence-translation, translation-check

I'm trying to translate Thomas Jefferson's sentence "priests dread the advance of science as witches do the approach of daylight."

After several discussions with my dictionary, I've come to a version that sounds pleasing to me, but I need to check whether the structure is right:

*Fugitur ut strigibus diluculum sic veritas presbyteris.*

I found no good word for witch, so I settled on *strix*, which seems to have meant a nightly beast resembling an owl, a vampire or a witch. Also, ancient Latin didn't have an equivalent for our *science*; their *scientia* was more like our *knowledge*. Does my translation work?

Comment: I wonder if Jefferson ever heard of Grosseteste, Copernicus, Mendel, Lemaître... (but that's neither here nor there)

Comment: @brianpck. Copernicus took minor orders, but there is no hard evidence that he was ever ordained as a priest.

Comment: @fdb Ah, no wonder he was capable of doing science then! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure seems good to me!

Literally, your sentence means "just as the dawn is fled by the *strigēs*, so is the truth by the elders". *Strigēs* is a good translation for "witches" because it captures both the malevolence and the nocturnal-ness; Ovid describes them as witches who transformed themselves with dark magic into blood-drinking owls.

The main concern I have is with *presbyterīs*, literally "elders". I'm not familiar with that word being used for priests in Classical Latin (though it might have taken on that meaning in Ecclesiastical); when I think of a "priest", my mind jumps to *sacerdos* or *flāmen*. You also used *fugiō* "flee from" instead of a verb like *timeō*, *horreō*, or *metuō* for "fear", which changes the meaning a bit but is an editorial decision.

Finally, *vēritās* "truth" is a good translation of "science" in this sense, but it doesn't have any implication of an approach or advancement. Again, that's an editorial decision, and it is certainly more concise without that extra word.

Comment: Thank you. The main reason why I used those specific words was to preserve the musicality: F**u**gitur ut str**i**gibus dil**u**culum sic v**e**ritas presb**y**teris.

Comment: Would *Fugitur ut strigibus diluculum sic scientia sacerdotis* be more exact?

Comment: @CarlosArturoSerrano I would use *sacerdōtis*, but if you specifically mean Christian priests I'm not the best person to ask about that. I'm sure there are much better words in Ecclesiastical Latin.

Comment: My dictionary includes Ecclesiastical Latin. It gives *sacerdos*, *presbyter* and *parochus*, and it reserves *flamen* for the Roman gods.

Comment: Hmm, my proposed revision seems to require a revision. Ablative should be *sacerdotibus*, right?

Comment: @CarlosArturoSerrano D'oh, yes, *sacerdōtibus*. To me a *parochus* is a professional host, someone who was paid to have supplies available for visiting bureaucrats and officers and whatnot.

Comment: Flamen is definitely a pagan priest, which is not intended here. I think you need sacerdos, which can be either a pagan or a Christian (e.g. in Hebrews 7,15).